# One i18n approach across js and java

Tags: javascript, java, internationalization

I realize this may not be the right place to ask this question so feel free to send me elsewhere. I am looking to internationalize a set of apps that have strings in a combination of java, tsp and javascript files. We have some use of resource bundles in a. few of the java apps but I am looking for a unified approach for all to both reduce the number of translation files and provide a single point of reference for them. I have yet to stumble upon a solution that is not specific to one or the other.

What I have thought of so far:

- Database-driven - this would achieve the two stated objectives but, unless I am missing something, would result in a lot of db calls and likely performance degradation.
- External files - this is the most feasible approach as I can read from a shared location. The only part I am struggling with is how to organize them so as to make it possible to load all the tags for, say, a single page together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the "External files" approach... decouple your translation files from your code... this would help your localization process a lot.

For i18n you might read this [article](https://medium.com/@jamuhl/i18n-frameworks-the-unfair-showdown-8d436cd6f470) (focus JavaScript but not only) ...

I would recommend looking into a i18n lib that is ready to be used in different frameworks, i.e. [i18next](http://i18next.com/docs/ecosystem/)
There is some java based lib too: i.e. [i18next-android](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-android)

As said in the beginning, you should not only consider that you have to instrument your code (i18n) to get your app/website translated. You should think about the process too - how will you solve [continuous localization](https://medium.com/@adriano_55049/continuous-development-integration-and-localization-continuous-deployment-40ca6b9be771), how you keep track of progress, etc...

For a translation management+ system you might eg. have a look at [locize](http://locize.com) it plays well with all json based i18n frameworks and in the core has a very simpe [api](http://locize.com/api.html)... and provides a lot more than traditional systems...